# Why does Solr's elevation not work with the subset option?

Tags: solr

**The problem**

Solr's `match="subset"` option lets you [elevate documents](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/query-elevation-component.html) if a query contains words from a pre-specified list. It doesn't seem to work.

In all experiments I've run, documents are only elevated if the query keywords are an exact match for those in the config file.

This feature was added in Solr 8.3 and a significant amount of the [elevation function](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/515af6d3ecc5ea1b3754776f9ce4e39857f99734/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/component/QueryElevationComponent.java) inside Solr exists purely to implement subset matching. But I've tried it in my own cores in Solr 9.3.0 and 8.11.2, and in Solr's techproducts sample database in Solr 9.3, 8.11.2, and 8.3.0, and it does not appear to work in any setting.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. From a terminal window, set up the techproducts example database, then switch Solr off:

```
solr -e techproducts
solr stop -all
```

2. Edit the `elevate.xml` file for the techproducts example (normally in `solr\example\techproducts\solr\techproducts\conf`) to be:

```
<elevate>
  <query text="foo bill" match="subset">
    <doc id="IW-02" />
  </query>
</elevate>
```

3. Restart solr's techproducts example (`solr -e techproducts`) and visit `http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/elevate?q=foo bill`. This will return the document with id IW-02, while queries such as `q=foo` or `q=foo bill bar` will not. But they should, because of the subset option.

Comment: `q=foo` probably shouldn't, since `foo bill` is not a subset of `foo` (which it would need to be according to my understanding of the documentation for 9.3)? Does `debug=all` tell you anything more?

Comment: Yes I agree about `q=foo` although the docs are rather tersely worded on this functionality which leaves some room for interpretation. `debug=all` doesn't [shed any light on it](https://pastebin.com/8AC2f0uB) other than saying that no match is found but maybe that output speaks to you more than me?! :)